# How to save Appium logs to a local text file?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, appium

I am using Appium to automate all my test cases related to IOS device using Java, Logs are currently displayed on Appium app itself. I want to save them in a text file so that i can check error after it finishes tests.

What I had tried:
1. I tried to use log4j, but it seems working with java console only not Appium.
2. I tried to use field available in Appium itself, but if i use it Appium do no start and shows undefined error, on research i find nobody uses that feature.

So I am not sure if we can do this or not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what have to tried to achieve this?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455145/how-to-get-appium-server-logs

Answer (score 0):

### Use `--log` command line option.

The appium command will take a `--log` option that allows you to specify where the log file should be written to, like this:

```
appium --log appium.log
```

This will cause the logs to be written to `./appium.log`.

Note: logs will also still be written to `stdout`. To send the `stdout` logs to a file instead, you could probably use something like this:

```
appium > appium.log
```